# what is the meaning of "-m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED"?

Tags: linux, networking

I found this rules on `iptables`

```
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

what is the meaning of `-m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED` ?

and why without this rule I can not ping `www.google.cn` ?

thank you very much ^_^

Comment: http://serverfault.com/q/371316/229499.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At it's most basic; it allows traffic in Both directions ***if you first request something***.
You probably can't Ping because the State isn't allowing any return data.

[See: User-land states](http://www.faqs.org/docs/iptables/userlandstates.html)